# How to select users friends post and users post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I need a way for MySQL to Select * From photos WHERE username is equal to "user" or "users friends".

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE username='king' OR username='$user' OR username='wale' OR username='prince'  ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Above, I played around to see what would work and this seems to work when I add the specific usernames. However, I would like for the program to automatically select the friends.

This is my original code. I need a way for my SQL to Select * From photos WHERE username is equal to user or "users friends".

```
$friendsArray = "";
$countFriends = "";
$friendsArray12 = "";
$addAsFriend = "";
$selectFriendsQuery = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
$friendRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectFriendsQuery);
$friendArray = $friendRow['friend_array'];
$friendArray = explode(",",$friendArray);
$countFriends = count($friendArray);
$friendArray12 = array_slice($friendArray, 0, 12); `
```

This selects the friends array within the database.
In the data base the friends are located under a column called friend_array. They are separated by a comma. For example (`'king,wale,prince'`)

```
if ($countFriends = $countFriends) {
    foreach ($friendArray12 as $key => $value) {
        $i++;
        $getFriendQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$value' LIMIT 1");
        $getFriendRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFriendQuery);
        $friendUsername = $getFriendRow['username'];
        $friendProfilePic = $getFriendRow['profile_pic']; `

        //$friendUsername each friend of the user. (King Prince Wale)
```

```
$get_photos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE username='$user' OR username='$friends' ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($get_photos);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_photos)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $uid = $row['uid'];
    $username = $row['username'];  
    $date_posted = $row['date_posted'];  
    $description = $row['description']; 
    $image_url = $row['image_url'];
```

This gets the users post and where I want it to select the users friends post.

```
echo "
<br>
<div class='albums'>
<div class='pic5656'>
<img src='$pro_pic2' height='30' width='30'>
</div>
<div class='name45'>$username $id</div> 
<div class='day56'>$date_posted</div>
<img src='$image_url' height='470' width='510'><br><br>
$description

<div style='float:left;'>
$button $countt
</div>

<a href='javascript:;' onClick='javascript:toggle$id()'><div  style='float: right; display: inline;'><img src='./img/more.png'></div></a>

  <div id='toggleComment$id' style='display:none;' >
  <iframe src='./comment_frame.php?id=$id' style='height: 70px; width: 100%; min-height: 10px; '></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
";
```

Finally this is where each post is displayed.

I need a way for my SQL to Select * From photos WHERE username is equal to user or "users friends".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) can save you a lot of code here:

```
SELECT *
FROM   photos
WHERE  username = '$user' OR
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FORM   users
               WHERE  username = '$user' AND
                      FIND_IN_SET (photos.username, friend_array) > 0)
```